# Mock SerialPort with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, node-serialport

I need to test the code working with SerialPort.
How to do it with jest? I tried to mock SerialPort and change the write method implementation:

protocol.js

```
import SerialPort from 'serialport'
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyS0')

function getCRC(data) {
  let crc = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    crc ^= data[i]
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      if (crc & 0x0001) crc = 0x08408 ^ crc >> 1
      else crc >>>= 1
    }
  }
  return Array.of(crc & 0xFF, crc >> 8 & 0xFF)
}

function reset() {
  let msg = Array.of(0x02, 0x03, 0x06, 0x30)
  msg = msg.concat(getCRC(msg))
  port.write(msg)
}

export { reset }
```

protocol.spec.js

```
import { reset } from './protocol'
import SerialPort from 'serialport'

jest.mock('serialport')

describe('test protocol commands', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    SerialPort.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        write: () => {
          throw new Error('test error')
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('should throw an error when calling reset command', () => {
    expect(() => reset()).toThrow()
  })
})
```

But it does not work. How to change the implementation correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old issue, but I finally found the correct answer as it is missing from the [documentation](https://serialport.io/docs/guide-testing). I will show the solution for the 10.x version of the module, as the testing API may have been different in previous versions.

I found an example of how to mock a SerialPort in the [Github Repository](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/blob/master/packages/serialport/examples/mocking.js). However, it seems to be somewhat out of date, so here is my solution using the information from the two resources.

```
import { MockBinding, MockPortBinding } from '@serialport/binding-mock';
import { SerialPort, SerialPortMock } from 'serialport';

// We override the SerialPort export so that SerialPortMock is used instead.
jest.mock('serialport', () => {
    return {
        ...jest.requireActual('serialport'),
        SerialPort: jest.fn().mockImplementation((options) => new SerialPortMock(options)),
    };
});

describe('Serial Port Mocking Example', () => {
    const path = '/dev/ROBOT';

    it('should sent data to port', (done) => {
        
        // We create a fake port
        MockBinding.createPort(path, { echo: false, record: false });
        
        // We create the port and connect to it
        const port = new SerialPort({ autoOpen: true, path, baudRate: 9600 });
        const data = 'test';

        // Once the port is open we can send it data
        port.on('open', () => {
            // We have to type coerce port.port as SerialPort the serial port class doesn't have a way to specify we are using MockPortBindings.
            (port.port as unknown as MockPortBinding).emitData(data);
        });
        
        port.on('data', (data) => {
            expect(data).toEqual(data);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`jest.mock` calls get hoisted by `babel-jest` so this line runs first:

```
jest.mock('serialport')
```

...which auto-mocks the `serialport` module.

`import` lines run next so `protocol.js` gets imported...and when it gets imported this line runs:

```
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyS0')
```

...which creates `port` using the empty auto-mocked implementation of `SerialPort`.

Then the `beforeAll` runs which creates the mock implementation for `SerialPort`, but this doesn't affect the `port` created in `protocol.js` since it has already been created.

---

There are a few ways you can fix it.

You can delay creating `port` until it is needed in `reset`:

```
function reset() {
  let msg = Array.of(0x02, 0x03, 0x06, 0x30)
  msg = msg.concat(getCRC(msg))
  const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyS0')  // <= create port here
  port.write(msg)
}
```

You can use a module factory function to create the mock:

```
import { reset } from './protocol'

jest.mock('serialport', () => {
  class MockSerialPort {
    write() {
      throw new Error('test error')
    }
  }
  return MockSerialPort;
});

describe('test protocol commands', () => {
  it('should throw an error when calling reset command', () => {
    expect(() => reset()).toThrow()  // Success!
  })
})
```

Or you can mock `write` on the `prototype` of `SerialPort`:

```
import { reset } from './protocol'
import SerialPort from 'serialport'

jest.mock('serialport')

describe('test protocol commands', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const mock = jest.spyOn(SerialPort.prototype, 'write');
    mock.mockImplementation(() => {
      throw new Error('test error')
    });
  })

  it('should throw an error when calling reset command', () => {
    expect(() => reset()).toThrow()  // Success!
  })
})
```